# Does PHP execute all logical operators in an operation?

Tags: php

I have tried searching the answer to my question in the following docs:

1. [PHP logical operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)
2. [PHP operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

### The question

What I'm trying to understand is if PHP does actually takes into account [Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm). An example would be:

```
// Complement Law
X + ~X = 1
```

Translating that into PHP code:

```php
if (true || false) {
  // logically it will evaluate to true due to `Complement law`
}

// in a more complicated example:

return true
  || false
  || true
  || true
  || true;

// a more real world example. Check for permissions of a certain user to a certain resource
return $this->canSeeResource()
  || $this->hasSuperPermission()
  || $this->isAdministrator();
```

**Does PHP takes into consideration the complement law when evaluating a boolean operation?**

In other words

**Does PHP executes all three methods (`canSeeResource`, `hasSuperPermission` and `isAdministrator`) if the first expression is true?**

### Why the question

I have the following logic to check if the user has the permission to see a certain resource:

```php
return $user->hasPermission(static::$MANAGE_ALL_ISSUES_PERMISSION_NAME)
            || $this->userIsOwnerAndHasPermissionToEditOwnIssues($user, $model)
            || $this->userHasSiteAndPermissionToManageSiteIssues($model, $user)
            || IssuePolicy::canAccessViaGroup($user, Issue::whereTodoId($model->id)->first())
            || $this->userAssignedAndIssueNotDoneOrDoneAndUserHasPermission($model, $user)
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny('User can not access todo.');
```

In this expression I would like to first check if a user has the permission `$MANAGE_ALL_ISSUES_PERMISSION_NAME` in order to be able to access this resource. Each one of these methods hits the database.

If PHP implements the `Laws and theorems of boolean algebra` in the first case (in the case that a user has the permission) we would exit the expression right away (as the first expression would be true), if not then I have to re-change my code to do:

```php
if ($user->hasPermission(static::$MANAGE_ALL_ISSUES_PERMISSION_NAME)) { return true; }

if ($this->userIsOwnerAndHasPermissionToEditOwnIssues($user, $model)) { return true; }

...
```

in order to save some hits to the database.

Comment: Why not run your code to check how this works? Putting some breakpoints or vardumps here and there could help

Comment: PHP uses short circuiting as long as the result is in accordance with the truth table. See suggested duplicate.

Comment: @CBroe exactly the answer I was looking for. I will vote to close the question as a duplicated. Thank you